# React - Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts, redux

I am trying to implement this [chart](http://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/KNeeEd?editors=1010) in my project

See the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/KNeeEd?editors=1010)

In my React application i have created this component called *ChartsGrid* where i am importing `LineChart from './d3/LineChart'` with his subcomponents `HorizontalAxis`, `VerticalAxis` and `LinePlot`

The state of the `data` is built correctly, i see it in the console

```
import React from 'react';
import Chart from './Chart';
import LineChart from './d3/LineChart';

export default class ChartsGrid extends React.Component{

  render() {

    const view = [480, 320];
    const trbl = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    const horizontalAxisHeight = 30;
    const verticalAxisWidth = 42;
    const { data } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="grid">
          <LineChart {...{view, trbl, data, horizontalAxisHeight, verticalAxisWidth}} />
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

i am getting this error in the console

[image]

It is complaining of my render method in `ChartsGrid` and i do not really understand what can be wrong. All the settings up seems fine to me, in the [previous codepen example](http://codepen.io/Mannaio/pen/KNeeEd?editors=1010) the only difference is that it is rendering the linechart data in `setTimeout` function.

What am i doing potentially wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `console.log('!!!!', LineChart)` and see if it is defined. Maybe you made a mistake importing/exporting

Comment: Yep, import/export mismatches are the most common reason for this error.  Given that `<LineChart`> is the only other thing being rendered, odds are it's not being imported properly.